extracting DTS-HD MA tracks from mkv files
I’d like to extract the DTS-HD MA tracks from several mkv files ripped from Blu-rays, and I’m looking to preserve to original audio quality.
I’ve extracted the tracks with FFMPEG and MKVToolNix.
For the file created by Handbrake, JRiver Media Center lists the bitrate as 3825, and on playback the bitrate spends a lot of time in the 4500’s and spikes as high as 23,000 kbps on orchestral flourishes.
The files created by FFMPEG and MKVToolNix have constant bitrates of 3767 and 3764, respectively, and play at noticeably lower volume and narrower dynamic range.
Handbrake will also put the DTS-HD MA track in an m4v container, which I couldn’t get to work in FFMPEG or MKVToolNix.
What’s the best way to extract an audio only DTS-HD MA file?
Also, which DTS-HD MA container file type has the widest compatibility?

It should be simple as:  ffmpeg -i your_file.mkv -map 0:2 -c copy your_file.dtshd

Thanks.  When I try the dtshd file format, I get this error: [AVFormatContext @ 000001bbc5b64440] Unable to choose an output format for 'D:/ffmpegoutput_0_1.dtshd'; use a standard extension for the filename or specify the format manually.
[out#0 @ 000001bbc59cb580] Error initializing the muxer for D:/ffmpegoutput_0_1.dtshd: Invalid argument
Error opening output file D:/ffmpegoutput_0_1.dtshd.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument

The command runs successfully with a .mka output file extension, but the output file has a constant, compressed bitrate.

My fault, I thought that extension was valid.  Try it with just .dts, it will likely work.  But I did find this saying: Name: Dolby TrueHD, File Formats: Audio and Music Dolby TrueHD, Extension(s): .thd .mlp ...so, it's .thd, according to google.

I would like to extract only the DTS files, convert them in AC3 5.1, and remux the audio in the original file. And those things automatically.
DTS is a not well adapted to the streaming, tat is why I need to convert DTS  to AC3 to all my MKV files which contains only one DTS audio track.
This AC3 conversion is at 640kb/s, and the DTS is at about 1500kb/s (some are at 755kb/s). It's a little loss of quality but not perceptible.
Here's my method:

Extract the DTS from the file: .\mkvextract.exe tracks "file.mkv" 1:"file.dts"
(in my case there is only a DTS tracks which ID is 1. In the file.mkv the video is track 0 for instance)
Create a 1.mkv file without the DTS: .\mkvmerge -o "file.1.mkv" --atracks !1 "file.mkv"
(--atracks !1 means : --atracks=audio track) and !1=without track 1)
Convert DTS to AC3 5.1: .\eac3to.exe  "file.dts" "file.ac3"
Lastly, merge the AC3 and the 1.mkv in a new.mkv file:  .\mkvmerge -o "file.new.mkv" "file.1.mkv" "file.ac3"

Here is the package which contains all the binaries
https://www.mangaluxe.com/tutoriels/download.php?id=logicielmkv
You should execute the cmds in the path of the folder logicielmkv (so you should do a cmd like : cd "C:\path\logicielmkv")
And here is the man page for mkvtoolnix prog if needed:
https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html
